# How can I change my laptop IP?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, proxy, ip

'm looking for a way to change my public IP address. You know that the one that other websites see.

I know what I'm looking for is basically a proxy server, but I don't want to use a proxy for 2 reasons:

1) It slows me down. 2) See reason

I'm using Ubuntu 9. I'm connecting to a public WiFi network (the ISP is Time Warner Cable). I'm getting my IP throug P.

Comment: -1 for taking the old question (which already has reasonable answers) and pasting it here almost word-for-word.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address that websites see depends on the external IP address of the network provider's router, i.e., the Time Warner router your system is using for its gateway to the Internet. Options for having websites see a different IP address other than using a proxy server are to use a [Virtual Private Network (VPN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or use [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29). There are many companies providing VPN service for a monthly fee. If you use Tor, websites won't know your actual external IP address, i.e., the one used by the ISP's router, but some will check on whether your connection is coming from a Tor node and restrict what you can do on the site. E.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) won't allow edits to articles and you should expect slower performance, though if you are just doing web browsing, the performance difference may not be so much that is problematical.

You mentioned that you don't want to use a proxy server, but other options may also result in a performance degradation. For the proxy server option, if you are using a free service that degradation is likely to be much more than if you are paying for a service, i.e., either buying proxy service from some company that provides such services or if you pay for a hosting service where you can install your own proxy server software.